# How can I free a char pointer that I have malloced? (I set the char pointer to NULL)

Tags: c, malloc

I want a free the char pointer which I have sent to NULL. Will this work? It doesn't seem to be freeing for me.

Comment: You don't free a pointer, you free a memory block (that was allocated with `malloc`).

Comment: Please update your question with your actual code. and an explanation of why  you think it's not working. Section 7 of the [comp.lang.c FAQ](http://www.c-faq.com/) might be helpful.

Comment: Could you add some code

Answer (score 1):

If you set it to null, reference of your allocation is lost unless you have saved it in some other variable. Freeing null will not do the job for you.